# Bondyield.php not working, why?

Tags: php, non-static

What am I doing wrong?

I am getting errors when using the script from this page. 
https://github.com/andy-sen/php-bond-yield

This is what is given as an example on the website, but does not work for me.

```
<?php
require_once 'bondyield.php';
printf("%f\n",BondYield::Calculate('2001-12-16',99, '2002-01-15',5,2,100));
```

I get 6 errors like this:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method BondYield::getDateParams() should not be 
called statically in public_html/00_test/bondyield.php on line 93
```

Thx!

Comment: because Calculate is not static function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
<?php
require_once 'bondyield.php';
$obj = new BondYield();
printf("%f\n",$obj->Calculate('2001-12-16',99, '2002-01-15',5,2,100));
```